# found ls binary using whereis but can't find ll why?

Tags: command-line, ls

found ls binary using whereis but can't find ll why ? How to find where ll binary loacted ?

I found "ls" binary using "whereis" but can't find "ll"

```
$ whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

But can't find ll :

```
$ whereis ll
ll:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the command attached to a bash alias?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102093/how-to-see-the-command-attached-to-a-bash-alias)

Comment: try `type -a ls ll`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash, what is command, utility, builtin, how do I distinguish](http://askubuntu.com/questions/355983/bash-what-is-command-utility-builtin-how-do-i-distinguish)

Comment: I think, what you @Ashish found was man pages and not the "binary" of ls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ll` is not a binary but an alias of the `ls -alF` command.

Check the `.bashrc` file :

```
$ alias ll
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

Comment: i want to call ll in shell script how to do that gives error : $ /bin/ll > /tmp/file
-bash: /bin/ll: No such file or directory

Comment: And, if I can add something, use `type`, which is a built-in in most shells, or `which` (`/usr/bin/which`) instead of `whereis`. Differently from `whereis`, those will detect aliases etc.

Comment: @kos `type`, yes, but `which` will not detect aliases. As you note, it's an executable `/usr/bin/which`, which does not have access to your shell aliases.

Comment: @WChargin Sorry, I mixed things up / phrased that badly. I use `zsh` an in `zsh` `which` is a built-in (and detects aliases). `/usr/bin/which` won't detect aliases; `which` in `zsh` (and I guess in other shells which have it as a built-in as well) will detect aliases.

Comment: @kos got it—good to know!

Comment: On some systems, /usr/bin/which can display aliases from bash when invoked as `alias | which -i`, which is itself often made an alias, as in `alias which="alias | which -i"`. Unfortunately, the version in Ubuntu seems to lack this feature, so while using which can apply generally, it doesn't here :-(

Answer (score 7):

As [noted by kos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694365/found-ls-binary-using-whereis-but-cant-find-ll-why/694530#comment1014978_694366) in the comments, you should use the [bash built-in `type` command](http://ss64.com/bash/type.html) which, unlike `whereis`, is also aware of aliases and shell built-ins:

```
$ type ll ls cd
ll is aliased to `ls -alF'
ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
cd is a shell builtin
```

(For the meaning of "hashed", see [this question on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105876/what-does-rm-is-hashed-mean).)

Comment: Will also work for bash functions: `testfunc() { echo 'Hi!'; }; type testfunc`.

Answer (score 6):

Many users like short cuts and this is what an alias is, a shortcut option for users.

Scripts should not use shortcuts, that is not a portable design, as you found out, these alias commands are not consistently defined.

Easiest answer to meet your need, assuming the use of 'll' is repeated:

Within the script, define the alias ll='ls -l', before referencing the command, then the use of 'll' will work throughout this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
alias  ll='ls -alF'
... (rest of the script)
```

Better Answer: better to use the full command in the script, provides documentation. Never use an alias in a script that others have to use.

Comment: This interface modified the script line, should begin with a 'hash' character followed by an 'exclamation' then /bin/bash as in '#!/bin/bash' assuming this is a bash script. This is the recommended first line of any bash script. This tells the system which shell to be used to interpret this script.

Comment: You just need to use code formatting. Select a snippet and hit CTRL+K or click the **`{}`** button. Or manually indent each code line with 4 spaces. That's the Markdown syntax used here on StackExchange. See http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting to learn more.

Comment: Muchos gracias, I was not aware of these formatting options. I see that you have modified my answer, much appreciated.